# WebForms imagebutton error with ASP.net 4.0 and IE10

Tags: windows-8, webforms, asp.net-4.0, internet-explorer-10

We had a user on Windows 8 Internet Explorer 10 get a "Input string was not in a correct format" exception on a legacy WebForms application. We did some research and found out that there is an existing bug in ASP.NET 4 with IE 10 and imagebutton controls not working properly when they are clicked.

One solution which doesn't require any code changes is to update the webserver with the .net framework 4.5 which will correct the bug. We did so on a test server and the bug goes away great!

My question is: **Does anyone know of any risks that could come with this solution of installing the .net framework 4.5? Is there a list of other issues with Windows 8 IE 10 and ASP.Net WebForms or MVC that we should be aware of?**

Details of the issue can be found here:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/755419/asp-net-4-0-and-ie10-click-on-imagebutton-in-updatepanel-produces-error-click-on-normal-button-does-not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing the .net framework 4.5 on the servers fixed the issue and we didn't see any other problems.

Answer (score 1):

[Scott Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx) described the issue over one year ago. The problem is a bug in a browser definition file where ASP.NET categorizes IE10 as an unknown browser.

The following hotfixes (.NET 2 and 4) should fix the described issue:

- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2600088
- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2600100